# get Aruba switch image file name in powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, aruba, kitty

I am writting a script to make updating of Aruba switch(2540) automatically with powershell. the script use two main thing. PowerArubaSw for checking switch Firmware etc. and kitty for uploading the new Firmware file from my PC with TFTP Protocol(tftpd software).

this is the line that I run Kitty to upload the file. it works correctly(I hope variable names are clear enough).

```
& $aruba.kittyPath $aruba.IP -ssh -l $aruba.user -pw $aruba.password -cmd "\s02 \n Copy tftp flash $($updateInfo.tftpServerIP) $($updateInfo.fileName) secondary \n y \n \s02 \n wri mem"
```

but after this line kitty shell will be open so, there will be two parallel process on system. 1.kitty 2.powershell script. and there is no comunication between them. therefore, the script does not know when it should go forwards. or easy saying, the Problem I have is that I do not know how to check if file is uploaded correctly to begin the installation in script.

[hier](https://community.arubanetworks.com/discussion/powerarubasw-a-powershell-module-for-use-arubaos-switch-rest-api) is explainted to use

```
show flash | include Image
```

to get the image files but it does not work for me. does anyone have Idea how I can go forward?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. Are you saying that the `& $aruba.kittyPath ...` line enters an interactive shell that blocks your script and you don't know how to programmatically exit that shell?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I try to clear it a bit more. this line do not block the script but it makes a parallel work. kitty prompt will open and upload the file successfully, at the same time my script go forwards and go to end.  the problem is how to comunicate between these two. or how I check the swicht with powershell in parallel to findout when file is uploaded and switch should be reset?